# AWS textract - UnsupportedDocumentException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

While implementing aws textract using boto3 for python.

Code:

```
import boto3

# Document
documentName = "/home/niranjan/IdeaProjects/amazon-forecast-samples/notebooks/basic/Tutorial/cert.pdf"

# Read document content
with open(documentName, 'rb') as document:
    imageBytes = bytearray(document.read())

print(type(imageBytes))

# Amazon Textract client
textract = boto3.client('textract', region_name='us-west-2')

# Call Amazon Textract
response = textract.detect_document_text(Document={'Bytes': imageBytes})
```

below are credential and config files of aws

```
niranjan@niranjan:~$ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id=my_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key=my_secret_access_key

niranjan@niranjan:~$ cat ~/.aws/config 
[default]
region=eu-west-1
```

I am getting this exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedDocumentException              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f52c10e3f3db> in <module>
     14 
     15 # Call Amazon Textract
---> 16 response = textract.detect_document_text(Document={'Bytes': imageBytes})
     17 
     18 #print(response)

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    314                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    315             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 316             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    317 
    318         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    624             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    625             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 626             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    627         else:
    628             return parsed_response

UnsupportedDocumentException: An error occurred (UnsupportedDocumentException) when calling the DetectDocumentText operation: Request has unsupported document format
```

I am bit new to AWS textract, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `DetectDocumentText` API of Textract does not support "pdf" type of document, sending pdf you encounter `UnsupportedDocumentFormat Exception`. Try to send image file instead.

Incase if you still want to send pdf file then you have to use Asynchronous APIs of Textract. E.g. `StartDocumentAnalysis` API to start analysis and `GetDocumentAnalysis` to get analyzed document.

> Detects text in the input document. Amazon Textract can detect lines of text and the words that make up a line of text. The input document must be an image in JPEG or PNG format. DetectDocumentText returns the detected text in an array of Block objects.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_DetectDocumentText.html

Comment: question with StartDocumentAnalysis, is it possible that the pdf file is in my temp folder or local folder? because aall the tutorial that I'm seeing the pdf file is in s3 bucket? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3
import time

def startJob(s3BucketName, objectName):
    response = None
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.start_document_text_detection(
    DocumentLocation={
        'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': s3BucketName,
            'Name': objectName
        }
    })

    return response["JobId"]

def isJobComplete(jobId):
    # For production use cases, use SNS based notification 
    # Details at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/api-async.html
    time.sleep(5)
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
    status = response["JobStatus"]
    print("Job status: {}".format(status))

    while(status == "IN_PROGRESS"):
        time.sleep(5)
        response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
        status = response["JobStatus"]
        print("Job status: {}".format(status))

    return status

def getJobResults(jobId):

    pages = []

    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
    
    pages.append(response)
    print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
    nextToken = None
    if('NextToken' in response):
        nextToken = response['NextToken']

    while(nextToken):

        response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId, NextToken=nextToken)

        pages.append(response)
        print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
        nextToken = None
        if('NextToken' in response):
            nextToken = response['NextToken']

    return pages

# Document
s3BucketName = "ki-textract-demo-docs"
documentName = "Amazon-Textract-Pdf.pdf"

jobId = startJob(s3BucketName, documentName)
print("Started job with id: {}".format(jobId))
if(isJobComplete(jobId)):
    response = getJobResults(jobId)

#print(response)

# Print detected text
for resultPage in response:
    for item in resultPage["Blocks"]:
        if item["BlockType"] == "LINE":
            print ('\033[94m' +  item["Text"] + '\033[0m')
```

Try this code and refer this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automatically-extract-text-and-structured-data-from-documents-with-amazon-textract/) from AWS for explanation